# Android XML to JSON conversion with Boolean enclosed within ""

Tags: android, ios, xml, json, cordova

I have used XML to JSON converter from json.org. My problem is that the Boolean & integers are  shown without double quotes in the converted JSON. 
My JSON has to be sent to UI which uses Javascript for Cordova app for iOS & Android app. Since conversion in iOS retains the double quotes when converting from XML to JSON, in Android also I have to retain them. In iOS there is no way remove the double quotes during conversion.

e.g. XML snippet

```
  <handle>
     <price>20</price>
     <item>chair</item>
     <tax>true</tax>
  </handle>
```

XML to JSON converter from json.org converts to

```
"handle": { "tax": true, "item": "chair", "price": 20 }
```

Expected to converted to following JSON

```
"handle": { "tax": "true", "item": "chair", "price": "20" }
```

Please let me know if there any other converting libraries/options using which this can be achieved?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/XML.java#L303

No.  At least not the 'easy' way.  Either use a different library or use this to build the JSON you want, but do your XML parsing manually and use `appendString` when building the JSON.

That said, I'm not sure this is really what you want.  You should reconsider *why* it is you need the "true" in string form, it seems highly likely to me that the real bug is somewhere else and this might be a way to avoid having to fix the real issue.  Not judging you, I've been there before.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think wrapping everything in quotes is the standard way, otherwise the parser is just going to interpret all values as strings. If that's what OP wants, it seems there's something wrong.

Comment: Thanks slf for the idea. I solved the issue by modifying the StringToValue method to return String always.

Comment: @user3274495 I cannot stress how bad of an idea this is.  Please do not do this in a production application.  Either contribute a patch with the option back to the original author or use a different library.